# Wish with would or past simple

Tags: past-simple, wish

I have trouble with the verb 'wish'. Searching this website, I could not find an answer to my questions, which is 'when we use **past simple** and when **would**?'

a) I wish I would live in LA --> This is a wish for the future.

b) I wish I lived in LA --> This is a regret that I, currently, do not live in LA.

So, for me, it seems that we can use **would** with action, durable verbs if we want something to happen in the future, and **past simple** with stative, durable verbs when we are not satisfied with the current situation (yet we know the changes are probably unreal).

Also, I have heard that we use **wish + would** *only* when we are annoyed about something and want it to change, but with the word 'only' it does not sound like the truth.

Comment: Your first sentence is unfortunately not idiomatic. "I wish you would come to LA" is OK, but that's "would" in the sense of intention. I can't really think of a way of expressing your sense of "wish for the future"; you would have to say something like "I hope to live in LA some day".

Comment: Or maybe "I wish I get the chance to live in LA some day."

Comment: While "I wish I would live in LA" seems completely wrong, if you express it as "I wish to live in LA", that is more correct -- although sounds stilted. You would probably write "I would love to live in LA" or "I want to live in LA".

Comment: Thank you, I think I've got this one. But we can still say, 'I wish it would be rainy tomorrow, right?

Comment: No, we don't say that. In a drought we can say "I wish it would rain" (meaning now or soon), but "I hope it will rain/be rainy tomorrow".